# Will update of included column of a non clustered index be performance intensive?

Tags: sql-server

I have a non-clustered index which contains few included columns. Will the update of included column of index (due to update of corresponding table row) be performance intensive ? How does database perform the update of included column of index ? Whether an index seek or index scan will occur to find the included column ? Database being used is SQL server.

Comment: Being performance intensive depends on how much you will query the index while is is being updated, how much power your server has and how many updates you will issue at this specific table/index. It all depends. Index updating is done in the background and should not be a problem in most of the cases. Is there a reason behind the question or is it just out of curiosity? Made if you stated your problem we could be more helpful

Comment: I would say that it would have a performance hit as the index needs to be updated, so in short that would imply a performance hit. As stated above, it will depend on the size of the table/index, and the activity on the table (lets say 100s of rows versus billions... and how many rows the update affects?)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I wanted to know this because I have an index whose included columns will get updated frequently. My actual question is: Whether an index seek or index scan of non clustered index will be performed to find the included column. The query plan does not gives information about the role of non clustered index in update of included column.